# Proof of Optional Stopping Theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Here is the theorem and proof presented in Probability and Random Processes (Grimmett).

**Theorem:** Let $(X, \pmb{\mathscr{F}})$ be a martingale and $\tau$ a stopping time. If $(i)$ $\tau$ is finite, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(\tau < \infty) = 1$
$(ii)$  $\mathbb{E}[|X_{\tau}|] < \infty$, and
$(iii)$  $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau > n\}}]=0$, then we have that the martingale property is preserved under random stopping. That is,
$\mathbb{E}[X_\tau] = \mathbb{E}[X_0]$.

**Proof:** It can be observed that $X_\tau = X_{\tau \wedge n} + (X_\tau - X_n)\cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau > n\}}$. Since $\tau \wedge n$ is a bounded stopping time, we know that the martingale property is preserved. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[X_\tau] =\mathbb{E}[X_0] + \mathbb{E}[X_\tau\cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau > n\}}] - \mathbb{E}[X_n\cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau > n\}}].$
Notice,

- $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n\cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau > n\}}] = 0$ by $(iii)$.
- $\mathbb{E}[X_\tau\cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau > n\}}] = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[X_k \cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau = k\}}]$ which is the tail of a convergent series by $(ii)$. Therefore, we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[X_k \cdot \mathbb{I}_{\{\tau = k\}}] = 0$

We have that $\mathbb{E}[X_\tau] = \mathbb{E}[X_0]$ as $n \to \infty$.

**Question:** I understand how parts $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ are being used to prove this theorem; however, I can't seem to figure out why we have part $(i)$ as another condition. Does anyone know how part $(i)$ comes into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without (i) the second condition does not even make sense. We are not assuming that the martingale is convergent. So what Is $X_{\tau}$ in (ii)?. It is defined only when $\tau <\infty$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand- are you saying that since we can't assume the martingale converges we don't know if $X_{\infty}$ exists. Therefore, $E[X_\tau]$ would be undefined if we did not restrict $\tau$ to be a.s finite?

Comment: @DorisP Exactly. This is why (i) is needed.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need part $(i)$ to justify that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\tau \wedge n) = \tau$ a.s

Comment: How so? because I thought that $E[X_{\tau \wedge n}] = E[X_0]$ irrespective of $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\tau \wedge n)$